# I cannot find the source of a print in Ruby on Rails website project. The array is printed sloppily above the table it is displayed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, output

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWBA.jpg). The information being printed is from the table creation below it I just cannot find out how to stop it without stopping the table from being printed as well.

Here is relevant code.

My index view for the projects file

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Hochschule München Student Projects</h1>
    <p class="lead">This website holds all the student led projects along with information about each of them.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Hochschule München Student Projects</h1>
    <p class="lead">This website holds all the student led projects along with information about each of them.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Listing projects</h1>

<br>

Filter by Professor
<%= collection_select(:project, :project_professor, Project.all.select(:project_professor).uniq, :project_professor, :project_professor, prompt: true) %>

<br> 

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "project_title", "Project Title" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "project_professor", "Professor" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "project_partner", "Partner" %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <%= @projects.each do |project| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= project.project_title %></td>
    <td><%= project.project_professor%></td>
    <td><%= project.project_partner%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project_path(project),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>

  <% end %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New project', new_project_path %>
```

And here is the controller file.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @projects = Project.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction); 0
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy

    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:project_title, :project_semester, :project_partner, :project_professor, :project_format, :project_department, :project_description, :project_image, :project_link) 
    end

    def sort_column
      Project.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "project_title"
    def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
    end

end
```

Thanks for any help! I've been having this problem for days now and cannot find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @projects.each do |project| %>



<tr>
    <td><%= project.project_title %></td>
    <td><%= project.project_professor%></td>
    <td><%= project.project_partner%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project_path(project),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>

  <% end %>
```

In Erb, <%= is used to write ruby code that will produce output and <% is used to write ruby code that will not produce output such as loops or conditionals.

Try writing your loop like this and see if that helps.

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
```

More info here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#erb

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= @projects.each do |project| %>
```

to

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
```

Remove `=` to avoid printing the return value of `each` method

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Hours of frustration solved by waiting 20 minutes online for complete strangers to save the day.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%= collection_select(:project, :project_professor, roject.all.select(:project_professor).uniq, :project_professor, :project_professor, prompt: true) %>
```

for

```
<% collection_select(:project, :project_professor, roject.all.select(:project_professor).uniq, :project_professor, :project_professor, prompt: true) %>
```

**The problem is the character "=" since it tells rails that it should show this variable and shows what the query brings**

Comment: This certainly led me on the right track since you explained what the '=' does, but deleting this just got rid of the drop-down. Thanks anyways I really appreciate all the random help I've gotten online. It's mind blowing how helpful the internet can be.